# Count the Number of Times a value is in a Column (With additional fields)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the below query to look for all entries that exist more than 1 time.

```
      SELECT p.Caption, COUNT(o.NodeID) as Count
      FROM
          NodesData p INNER JOIN
          Interfaces o ON o.NodeID = p.NodeID

      GROUP BY p.Caption, o.Caption

      HAVING Count(o.NodeID) > '1'
```

The query works fine.  However, I would like to add additional data to the Select.  When doing this, it breaks the query because all of the counts are 1.  How do I get the query to still do an accurate count while allowing view of the additional data.  See below for example.

```
      SELECT p.Caption, o.Caption, COUNT(o.NodeID) as Count
      FROM
          NodesData p INNER JOIN
          Interfaces o ON o.NodeID = p.NodeID

      GROUP BY p.Caption, o.Caption

      HAVING Count(o.NodeID) > '1'
```

Comment: Have you tried `row_number()` ?

Comment: Please tag your DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.Caption, o.Caption as InterfaceCaption, COUNT(o.NodeId) OVER (PARTITION BY p.Caption) as NodeCount
    FROM
       NodesData p
       INNER JOIN Interfaces o
       ON o.NodeId = p.NodeId
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    NodeCount > 1
```

Use `COUNT() OVER` *window function* in a *Common Table Expression* (or derived table) and then add your where clause.  Otherwise you would have to take your result of your first query and join back to your tables to retrieve the other details you want.

you can also use the join back to the original tables method but its more verbose in my opinion:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT p.Caption, COUNT(o.NodeID) as Count
    FROM
       NodesData p INNER JOIN
       Interfaces o ON o.NodeID = p.NodeID
    GROUP BY p.Caption, o.Caption
    HAVING Count(o.NodeID) > '1'
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte c
    INNER JOIN NodesData p
    ON c.Caption = p.Caption
    INNER JOIN Interfaces o
    ON p.NodeId = o.NodeId
```

Comment: This worked great.  Thank you.  The only change I had to make was to add o.Caption as InterfaceName.  Without modifying the column name I was getting The column 'Caption' was specified multiple times for 'cte'.

Comment: @mprobus yeah you would get that errir because caption was specified twice. aliasing it as anything unique, such as InterfaceName like you did was the perfect way of rectifying  glad to be of help. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting ones because o.Caption is different on every row on Interfaces, you could trick o.Caption by doing a MAX on it like the following:

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/487628/2)

Comment: this would arbitrarily pick a o.Caption value based on its ascending order and would not return all of the related values